# Removing a breakpoint from running code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

When I am testing my code and have a breakpoint set, it will stop when it hits it.

I can then unclick the breakpoint and continue testing different areas of my code.
Except (although unclicked) the breakpoint is still stored, and stops at the same point every time it passes this code.

Stopping the code and removing the breakpoint works - is there an easier way to do this without me stopping debugging?

Answer (score 2):

I think you did remove the break points on runtime. So if you remove the breakpoint in runtime. It wont save. So it will hit the same place again.

Please remove the breakpoint in normal mode (before debugging).

let me know if it is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable or remove all break points from debug menu. As you can see to delete all break points you need to press **ctrl+shift+F9**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Shift + F9 will remove all breakpoints from your project.  I use this to clear all breakpoints efficiently.

If you remove a breakpoint it will not hit anymore.  If it does there may be something wrong with your project